# show label output as decimal

Tags: xcode4.2, decimal

I currently have 2 text fields where users enter full numbers, these are then multiplied together and divided by 100 to get a desired number and shown in a label, i.e. 2400x1200/100=288.
My issue is I require the resulting number to be shown as "2.88" not "288" how can i achieve this?

My code as below

```
- (IBAction)myTextField:(id)sender {
}

- (IBAction)mySecondTextField:(id)sender {
}

- (IBAction)calculate {
int num1 = self.myTextField.text.intValue;
int num2 = self.mySecondTextField.text.intValue;
self.myLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2d m2", num1 * num2 / 10000];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use -

```
self.myLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", num1 * num2 / 10000.0];
```

instead of 10000, you need to use 10000.0. And only %0.2f is sufficient as format.

Comment: Thank you rishi worked great just also needed to change to 1000000.00